# Ansible grep for a line continuously

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I know how to check if certain line is available on a file using the below task, but I'm not sure how to check or grep a file continuously  until the mentioned line appears and exit the task.(-= SERVICE HAS BEGUN =-)

```
 - name: Check whether my.log contains "SERVICE HAS BEGUN"
  command: grep -Fxq "-= SERVICE HAS BEGUN =-" my.log
  register: logg
  check_mode: no
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: no
```

I've came across wait_for option but that really not helps the case. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could so something using an [`until` loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops), like this:

```
- name: Check whether my.log contains "SERVICE HAS BEGUN"
  command: grep -Fxq -- "-= SERVICE HAS BEGUN =-" my.log
  register: logg
  ignore_errors: true
  changed_when: false
  until: logg.rc == 0
  retries: 60
  delay: 2
```

This will retry for about 2 minutes (60 times with a 2 second delay between tries).

Note that I've had to modify your `grep` command, because otherwise the leading `-` in your search string would cause `grep` to interpret that as a command line option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use wait_for, you can - it can wait for a regex to appear in a file:

```
- name: Wait until SERVICE HAS BEGUN
  wait_for:
    path: /path/to/my.log
    search_regex: SERVICE HAS BEGUN
```

You should definitely add some timeout values here - check the docs to see what the defaults are, and set something appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Nice knowing the alternate approach :) Thanks